# WCF bypassProxyOnLocal - What determines local?

Tags: wcf

I have added a WCF service to an existing ASP.Net web project on our test website (only accessible on company network). I can access the service by typing the URL in a browser, but if I add a service reference to a web project, I get a runtime error that 'the remote name could not be resolved'.

In my web.config, I have the bypassProxyOnLocal binding attribute set to 'true' (we use a proxy on the company network), but it seems as though our test domain is not recognized as a local domain (or recognized at all, really). Again, this is only when I add it as a service reference. Obviously the domain is valid, because I can add it as a service reference, and can event paste the URL into a browser, and it works. I just get a runtime error after I add it as a service reference. Anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this resolved. The request was somehow being blocked by the company network.

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN [WSHttpBindingBase.BypassProxyOnLocal Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wshttpbindingbase.bypassproxyonlocal.aspx), "An Internet resource is local if it has a local address. A local address is one that is on same computer, the local LAN or intranet and is identified, syntactically, by the lack of a period (.) as in the URIs "http://webserver/" and "http://localhost/".

If your test domain is "http://test.mycompany.com/", then it won't be viewed as a local address.  Perhaps using "http://test/" in this case would work?

Comment: Okay, let me start over in a more simple environment. I have now added a WCF service to the production site that simply returns the "Hello World" string. I have created a test page that consumes the service, and displays the return value in an ASP.Net Literal control. I receive the following message when attempting to consume the service:

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.